# disable click event for nested div elements until setTimeout is over

Tags: javascript, events, nested, click, settimeout

I have this script where I highlight the clicked div and its parents, then I make them white again respectively. However, I would like to stop consecutive clicks, allow only one click **until setTimeout finishes**. Basically, user should wait for the whole animation to finish before clicking again.

```
const allDivElements = document.querySelectorAll("div");

let timeout = 300;
allDivElements.forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this, true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        changeBg(this, false);
        timeout = 300;
      }, timeout);
    }, timeout);
    timeout += 300;
  });
});

function changeBg(div, phase) {
  if (phase) div.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  else div.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
}
```

As far as I looked over the possible solutions, I was not able to find one that prevents click events until setTimeout methods. Any detailed help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry if I cause confusion. This is the link to the whole application in case you'd like to test it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-goldstine-ope9w?file=/src/index.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make this too complicated. Just use a Boolean value for each element to track whether the click should work or not:

```
const timeout = 300;
allDivElements.forEach((div) => {
  let clickAllowed = true;
  div.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (clickAllowed) {
      clickAllowed = false;
      changeBg(this, true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        changeBg(this, false);
        clickAllowed = true;
      }, timeout);
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this script is that in the second setTimeout method, you enable click event again with "clickAllowed = true", which means even if div elements are not clickable during highlighting process, it will be so when making them white again.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I did indeed think that was what you wanted - to prevent clicks for the duration of the timeout. If you really want to disable *all* subsequent clicks then you can easily remove the line - although there are better and easier ways to add an event handler than only works once.

Answer (score 0):

- Handle your listeners using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`
- Once all the elements are processed, add back the events using `addEventListener`
- A recursion could also come handy to iterate over parent Elements:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const EVT = (el, t, n, f, o = {}) => el.forEach(e => e[`${{on:"add",off:"remove"}[t]}EventListener`](n, f, o));

const changeBg = (div) => {
  if ([...divs].indexOf(div) < 0) return EVT(divs, "on", "click", clickHandler); // Add
  
  div.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  setTimeout(() => {
    div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    changeBg(div.parentElement); // Recursive call, this time pass the parent
  }, 300);
};

const clickHandler = async(ev) => {
  EVT(divs, "off", "click", clickHandler); // Remove listeners
  changeBg(ev.currentTarget); // Start
};

EVT(divs, "on", "click", clickHandler); // Add listeners
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">1
  <div id="2">2
    <div id="3">3
      <div id="4">4
        <div id="5">5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice answer, I will definitely read and understand it carefully! I wonder if it will work for nested divs since this is my case. I appreciate you for your help no matter what though! Also sorry for not adding any extra code indicating my layout. I've just added a codesandbox link where I work on this little project, you can also try it out to see what I mean if you wish